# 404 on all Category Pages

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, category, magento2-migration-tool, ce-1.8.1.0

Have upgraded from 1.8.1.0 to 2.3.3.

But every single category page is now 404'd.

Have truncated a **`url_rewrite`** and **`catalog_url_rewrite_product_category`**, but no luck.

Have gotten rid of the other root and clear:cached and re-indexed.

Other symptoms: All of the form fields in the categories are blank.

Would very much appreciate any help, thank you!
[image: Admin panel screenshot of Blank Fields (whose attributes have data)]

--Just to note CMS rewrites are working fine, however "http://host/catalog/category/view/id/[id]" returns 404, so doesn't seem to be a rewrite problem.

Comment: Did you run reindexing?

Comment: Which os you are using? can i view your .conf file?

Comment: Hi guys, yup have reindexed - runs fine, am running Centos6: the category rewrites work fine both in the default 2.3.4 install and 1.8.1.0, so I think it has to be a data corruption issue in the DB; have not installed any modules at all. Cheers!